# How can I calculate the self-convolution-like integration?

Tags: integration, convolution

Assume $f(x)$ is a real, differentiable and continuous function over $R$, I want to calculate an integration :
$$
\lim_{a\to \infty} \int_0^a f^m(x) \frac{df(a-x)}{d(a-x)}dx.
$$
where $m$ is any positive integer. The conditions are: $f(x) = f(-x)$,  $f(0) = 1$, $\frac{df}{dx}|_{x=0} = -1$, and $f(\infty)$ is also known, defined as $f_{\infty}$. I tried in this way:
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^a f^m(x) \frac{df(a-x)}{d(a-x)}dx \\
&= -\int_0^a f^m(x) \frac{df(a-x)}{dx}dx  \\
&=  -\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^a f^m(x)  f(a-x) dx \\
\end{align}
$$
Here I use the relation that the derivation is distributive over the convolution. I am also not sure that whether the calculation is correct. Then I can not go any further.

Could someone give me some suggestions on this problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f^m(x)\frac{df(a-x)}{d(a-x)}dx\tag{1}$$
notice that:
$$\frac{d(a-x)}{dx}=-1$$
and so:
$$\frac{1}{d(a-x)}=-\frac 1{dx}$$
which gives:
$$(1)=f^m(x)df(a-x)$$
and so your integral is:
$$-\int_0^af^m(x)df(a-x)$$
if we let $u=(a-x)$ then $dx=-du$ and so:
$$I=\int_a^0f^m(a-u)df(u)$$
$$=-\int_0^af^m(a-u)f'(u)du$$
as $a\to\infty$ I believe we have:
$$I=-\int_0^\infty f_\infty^mf'(u)du=-f_\infty^m\left[f(u)\right]_0^\infty=f_\infty^mf(o)-f_\infty^{m+1}$$

Comment: Thanks. What still troubles me is why f(a-u) can be replaced by f∞ when it is inside the integral sign. Because it is a function of variable u.

Answer (score 1):

You can't calculate the exact value of the integration, because the $f$ is unknown. But you can get the limit of the integration as $a \to \infty$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.